# How to use GET request to obtain JSON

Tags: php, json

Need code demonstrating a HTTP GET request to obtain some JSON, decode it, and iterate over the top level objects, assuming the format:

[{},{},{},...]

Comment: `Need code` never works here

Comment: No way anybody is gonna help you. What have you tried? Do you have some code examples?

Comment: Did you google it? https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=HTTP%20GET%20JSON%20PHP

Comment: @ Vincent Yes ,I google it , But even I am not understand what they are asking.they ask in test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url='http://api.example.com/';
$url.='?id='.urlencode($id);//append id as get
$url.='category='.urlencode($category);//append category as get
$response=file_get_contents($url);
//suppose api response is as ['name','created_at','category','id','other_data'];

$data=json_decode($response);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    //do your stuff
}
```